# Wrong path with drupal.add.js

Tags: javascript, uri

The problem occurs when a node alias consists of a backslash.

My example:

```
drupal_add_js(path_to_theme() . '/js/script.js', array(
    'type' => 'external', 
    'scope' => 'footer', 
    'weight' => 5
));
```

Now I have a node with the alias EXAMPLE/example.html

The path to the script.js is now **`domain.com/EXAMPLE/sites/all/themes/example/js/script.js`** and not **`domain.com/sites/all/themes/example/js/script.js`**

What do I do to make the path right?

Answer (score 0):

Try making it absolute:

```
$options = array(
  'type' => 'external', 
  'scope' => 'footer', 
  'weight' => 5,
  'absolute' => TRUE
);
drupal_add_js(path_to_theme() . '/js/script.js', $options);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid that by making the path absolute starting from the base path of your Drupal install. You can use the [`base_path()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/base_path/7) function get the base path (which really just returns the GLOBAL `$base_path` with a slash (`/`) added to the beginning and end, or just a slash if there is no base path.

```
$options = array(
  'type' => 'file', 
  'scope' => 'footer', 
  'weight' => 5,
);
drupal_add_js(base_path() . path_to_theme() . '/js/script.js', $options);
```

Also, "type" should be set to "file" unless you're loading an external file with a full path.